# Javascript issue unable to assign submit on enter

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

We are working on creating a woocommerce portal and implementing filters. Now the issue here is when we try to disable autosubmit in the code and assign the same to enter key it doesnt work please see the code below -

```
  jQuery(function () {
    //woof_init_mselects();
});
function woof_init_mselects() {
    try {
        // jQuery("select.woof_select").chosen('destroy').trigger("liszt:updated");
        jQuery("select.woof_mselect").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
    } catch (e) {
    }
    jQuery('.woof_mselect').change(function () {
        var slug = jQuery(this).val();
        var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
        woof_mselect_direct_search(name, slug);
    });
}
function woof_mselect_direct_search(name, slug) {
    //mode with Filter button
    var values = [];
    jQuery('.woof_mselect[name=' + name + '] option:selected').each(function (i, v) {
        values.push(jQuery(this).val());
    });
    values = values.join(',');
    if (values.length) {
        woof_current_values[name] = values;
    } else {
        delete woof_current_values[name];
    }     
    woof_ajax_page_num = 1;
      /** Autosubmit option */
   if (woof_autosubmit) {
    woof_submit_link(woof_get_submit_link()); //Here it is referring the link for submission which is "Filter"  
   }
}
```

Please suggest how do we alter it to assign enter key for submission.
Please note its not a form but Filters are being used.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some more information? Like what what is the current functionality and what you want to change in that?

Comment: At present whenever we select any option in dropdown or checkboxes it autosubmits it and shows us the results. However, what we wanted to achieve is when making multiple selections enter key should be assigned to submit the query. You can check the functionality here www.bookworldltd.com/shop/

Comment: Well, what I see on your link is that, are there total of 4 product filters (in left column). 'Product Categories', 'Select Year(s) of Publication', 'Publisher' and 'Binding Detail'. I hope these are the filters you are referring to. I do not see it submitting automatically on selection. It gets submitted only after the "Filter" button is clicked.

Comment: Yes thats right the autosubmit is off from woo-commerce backend however, what we need is as soon as user is done with selection he/she must be able to submit it by pressing the enter key instead of doing a mouse click on Filter button.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use "keydown" EventListener.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", filterButtonAction, false);
//event handler function
function filterButtonAction(e){
   //check to see if filter submit button is present on page
   if( $('button.woof_submit_search_form').length > 0 ){
     //13 is key code for "Enter" key
     if(keyCode==13) {
         //your desired functionality
     }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.